# Add text to TextView in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

How to add text to existing text in an Android TextView.

Here is my idea:

> Another journey chamber way yet females man. Way extensive and dejection get delivered               deficient sincerity gentleman age. Too end instrument possession contrasted motionless.     Calling offence six joy feeling. Coming merits and was talent enough far. Sir joy northward     sportsmen education. Discovery XXXXXXXXXXXXX earnestly no he commanded if. Put still any about      manor heard.

I want the text I have to add to be in place of XXX symbols. Are there any markers that can make this possible?

Comment: is that ace ventura or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xml (strings.xml):

```
<string name="string_with_formatting">
...... Discovery %1$s earnestly no he commanded if. Put still any about manor heard.
</string>
```

From code:

```
String mXXX = "My XXXXXX string";
final String text = String.format(getString(R.string.string_with_formatting), mXXXX);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no marker during run time, if you want to change it over sertain interval(i.e. every 1min). You have to do it thgough String manupulation & then set the formated string again to the textview.